# Using Python script in NodeJS on GAE

Tags: python, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using a Python script in NodeJS like so:

```
const app = express();
const ps = require('python-shell');
var res_json;
var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python',
    scriptPath: './peframe/peframe',
    args: ['--json' ,'/home/mypath/IP.exe']
};
ps.PythonShell.run('peframe.py', options, function (err, results) {
   if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
  res_json=results.join('');
});
```

But, if deploy this app, it can't find Python (but it works locally) The
error is:

```
Error: spawn /usr/bin/python ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:232)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407)
    at process._tickCallback (next_tick.js:63)
    at Function.Module.runMain (loader.js:744)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739)
```

Comment: Post the code as text.. not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ENOENT` error means that the `/usr/bin/python` path does not exist. This is because you're using the NodeJS runtime -- it doesn't have Python available.

If you really need to run NodeJS and Python in the same app, you can deploy them as separate services within the same app.